# Call a token of rule B from rule A

Tags: antlr, token, rule

I would like to know if and how I can call a token of rule B from rule A, as in the example below:

//Rule A

description 
:'Description' ':' primaryActor.actorName ...... //I tried this way, but it doesn't work. 
;

//Rule B1

primaryActor 
:actorName PA_TYPE 
;

//Rule B2

secondaryActor 
:actorName SA_TYPE 
;

actorName 
:ARTICLE SMALL_NOUN 
; 
/* ... */

So, 'primaryActor' and 'secondaryActor' both have an 'actorName'. If we write a test in the interpreter such as "Description: a Doctor...", 'Doctor should be assigned to 'primaryActor.actorName. Because 'actorName' is of the same type for both primary and secondary actors, I don't want to create an actorName for each one of them but being able to distinguish the actorName through its  including rule.

Comment: As I already [commented on the mailing-list](http://antlr.markmail.org/message/wtaqsl3qye5khng2?q=how+to+call+a+rule): I don't quite follow what it is you're trying to do (and your follow up comment didn't clarify it, btw). But it looks to be you're (again) cramming too much semantic checks inside the parser and it looks to me you don't have enough ANTLR knowledge to know what's possible with ANTLR and what is best handled after parsing (I could be wrong, of course, but I get this impression). Best of luck though!

Comment: Hi Bart, I am sorry I didn't know that it's you who commented on the mailing list regarding this question. Surely, I am a beginner in ANTLR, but what I want is to write a grammar in EBNF, which the reader will follow to write use case description. I just wanted to add some extras to this EBNF grammar, such as passing parameters to a rule, which is something I managed to do with your help. And now this is the new addition I would like to have, which it is probably irrelated to EBNF or ANTLR. I will try to upload an image (if this feature is provided) to show you what I would like to do.